Ubuntu 22.04 | Error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1/blockcount) connection refused
good day,
I'm running a Bitcoin node on Ubuntu 22.04, Have Bitcoin Ordinals library installed and trying to listen to Ord server using below command:
ord --cookie-file ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/.cookie server --http-port 8080
I'm listening to port 8080 because ports under 1024 are only for root access as i'm using a normal user to run the node. also think that Ord library is listening to port 80 by default.
I've created a wallet and all good, but when i try to get wallet address using below command, i get the error,
ord --cookie-file ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/.cookie wallet receive
Error: error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1/blockcount): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
Appreciate if anyone can help.
Tried to listening to a different port, same issue.
tried to change Ord library source code to listen to different port but couldn't locate the right file.
Tried to give permissions for normal user to listen to port 80 but no luck.

Solved,
ord --cookie-file ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/.cookie wallet --server-url http://0.0.0.0:8080 receive

Fixed using below command,
ord --cookie-file ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/.cookie wallet --server-url http://0.0.0.0:8080 receive
